# Closed network DHCP+DNS - updating in-addr.arpa side works, forward side refuses to update

Tags: dns, dhcp

I am struggling with one small problem in our closed network. I built new DNS and DHCP and everything works, except DNS refuses to update file with forwarding information sent from DHCP. I have tried multiple changes to dhcpd.conf, checked and rechecked file and directory privileges and so on.
Apologies for showing modified files and not the original ones, sensitive data has been changed.
Result of this problem can be seen on two nslookup examples:

```
$ nslookup
> testname1
Server:    10.0.0.100
Address:   10.0.0.100#53
** server can't find testname1: REFUSED

> 10.0.0.101
Server:    10.0.0.100
Address:   10.0.0.100#53
101.0.0.1.in-addr.arpa     name = testname1.example.com.
```

As you can see, looking up the name of the client does not work, but asking for the IP address works. This happens when the client PC is not predefined in forward and reverse zone files and DHCP is supposed to send the data. Reverse file gets updated, forward file is not modified.
When client asks DHCP for address, this happens, according to named.run log:

```
nov 07 08:51:41 localhost.localdomain dhcpd[2744]: DHCPREQUEST for 10.0.0.101 from 1a:2b:3c:4d:5e:6f via ens32
nov 07 08:51:41 localhost.localdomain dhcpd[2744]: DHCPACK on 10.0.0.101 to 1a:2b:3c:4d:5e:6f via ens32
nov 07 08:51:41 localhost.localdomain named[2549]: client 127.0.0.1#42022/key rndc-key: signer "rndc-key" approved
nov 07 08:51:41 localhost.localdomain named[2549]: client 127.0.0.1#42022/key rndc-key: updating zone '0.0.10.in-addr.arpa/IN': deleting rrset at '101.0.0.10.in-addr.arpa' PTR
nov 07 08:51:41 localhost.localdomain named[2549]: client 127.0.0.1#42022/key rndc-key: updating zone '0.0.10.in-addr.arpa/IN': adding an RR at '101.0.0.10.in-addr.arpa' PTR
nov 07 08:51:41 localhost.localdomain dhcpd[2744]: Added reverse map from 101.0.0.10.in-addr.arpa. to hostname1.example.com
nov 07 08:51:44 localhost.localdomain dhcpd[2744]: DHCPINFORM from 10.0.0.101 via ens32
nov 07 08:51:44 localhost.localdomain dhcpd[2744]: DHCPACK to 10.0.0.101 (1a:2b:3c:4d:5e:6f) via ens32
nov 07 08:51:44 localhost.localdomain named[2549]: client 10.0.0.101#54095: update 'example.com/IN' denied
nov 07 08:51:44 localhost.localdomain named[2549]: client 10.0.0.101#55624: update 'example.com/IN' denied
```

If you look closely on who is requesting what, you can see my problem, update request for 0.0.10.in-addr.arpa/IN is requested by 127.0.0.1, forward update request is made by 10.0.0.101, instead of 127.0.0.1 . And of course, security policy in named.conf defines that only someone with DNSSEC key can update the zones.

**dhcpd.conf**

```
authoritative;
option domain-name "example.com";
option domain-name-servers ns1.example.com;
default-lease-time 72000;
max-lease-time 72000;
ddns-update-style interim;
ddns-updates on;
update-static-leases on;
ddns-domainname "example.com";
###allow client-updates;
###ignore client-updates;
###do-forward-updates;  #if uncommented, this line crashes dhcpd at start, with strange errors reported in config file.
key "rndc-key" {
   algorithm hmac-md5;
   secret "secret-DNS-key";
};

subnet 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 10.0.0.110 10.0.0.120;
  option broadcast-address 10.0.0.255;
  option domain-name-servers 10.0.0.100;
  option domain-name "example.com";
  option routers 10.0.0.1;
}

zone example.com. {
  primary localhost;
  key rndc-key;
}

zone 0.0.10.in-addr.arpa. {
  primary localhost;
  key rndc-key;
}

host testname1 {
  option host-name "testname1.example.com";
  hardware ethernet 1a:2b:3c:4d:5e:6f;
  fixed-address 10.0.0.101;
}
```

**named.conf**

```
options {
        listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; 10.0.0.100;}; #IP address of DNS server and localhost
#       listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
        directory       "/var/named";
        dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
        allow-query     { localhost; 10.0.0.0/24;}; #which computers can ask
        allow-transfer  { localhost; }; #No backup DNS server yet
        recursion no;   #no connection to internet, to speed up requests for unknown names and domains.

        dnssec-enable yes;
        dnssec-validation yes;

        /* Path to ISC DLV key */
        bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";

        managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";

        pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
        session-keyfile "/run/named/session.key";

/*      forwarders {                    #nothing, so far
                10.0.0.100
        }
*/
};

logging {
        channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run";
                severity dynamic;
        };
};

zone "." IN {
        type hint;
        file "named.ca";
};

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";
include "/etc/rndc.key";

zone "example.com." IN {
  type master;
  file "data/example.com";
  allow-update {key rndc-key;};
#  allow-update {127.0.0.1;10.0.0.0/24;};
};

zone "0.0.10.in-addr.arpa." IN {
  type master;
  file "data/0.0.10.in-addr.arpa";
  allow-update {key rndc-key;};
#  allow-update {127.0.0.1;10.0.0.0/24;};
};
```

**ls -al /var/named/data**

```
drwxrwx---. 2 named named    4096  7. nov 10.11 .
drwxrwx---. 7 named named    4096  7. nov 09.02 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 named named    1810  7. nov 10.11 example.com
-rw-r--r--. 1 named named    2640  7. nov 09.58 example.com.jnl
-rw-r--r--  1 named named 1494887  7. nov 10.34 named.run
-rw-r--r--  1 named named    2353  7. nov 10.10 0.0.10.in-addr.arpa
-rw-r--r--. 1 named named    8010  7. nov 09.58 0.0.10.in-addr.arpa.jnl
```

**forward zone file, example.com**

```
$TTL 604800     ; 1 week
example.com                IN SOA  ns1.example.com. admin.example.com. (
                            2016110411 ; serial
                            604800     ; refresh (1 week)
                            86400      ; retry (1 day)
                            2419200    ; expire (4 weeks)
                            604800     ; minimum (1 week)
                            )
                    NS      ns1.example.com.

testname2                A       10.0.0.102
```

**reverse zone file, 0.0.10.in-addr.arpa**

```
$TTL 604800     ; 1 week
0.0.10.in-addr.arpa   IN SOA  ns1.example.com. admin.example.com. (
                            34         ; serial
                            604800     ; refresh (1 week)
                            86400      ; retry (1 day)
                            2419200    ; expire (4 weeks)
                            604800     ; minimum (1 week)
                            )
                    NS      ns1.example.com.

102                       PTR     testname2.example.com.
```

I can easily fix this problem by changing named.conf to allow updates from 10.0.0.0/24 and without key - I have already tested that it works - but security would be laughable. I am looking for better answer.
Why is reverse file request processed as from localhost and forward file as from client's IP and how to fix it?

EDIT: adding results of "dig" test:

**dig 10.0.0.101**

```
; <<>> DiG 9.4.2-P2 <<>> 10.0.0.101
;; global options:  printcmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 14648
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;10.0.0.101.                  IN      A

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 10.0.0.100#53(10.0.0.100)
;; WHEN: Tue Nov  8 09:43:50 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 30
```

**dig testname1**

```
; <<>> DiG 9.4.2-P2 <<>> testname1
;; global options:  printcmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 60894
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;testname1.                         IN      A

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 10.0.0.100#53(10.0.0.100)
;; WHEN: Tue Nov  8 09:44:07 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 23
```

**dig testname1.example.com**

```
; <<>> DiG 9.4.2-P2 <<>> testname1.example.com
;; global options:  printcmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 40151
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;testname1.example.com.                        IN      A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
example.com.               604800  IN      SOA     ns1.example.com. admin.example.com. 2016110411 604800 86400 2419200 604800

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 10.0.0.100#53(10.0.0.100)
;; WHEN: Tue Nov  8 09:44:15 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 78
```

Comment: Please [read this](https://wiki.debian.org/DDNS). Maybe a `notify no` is needed.

Comment: Also test your sever with `dig` (from dnsutils package), is a better tool for testing DNS servers. Anyway, what do you get with the full name `nslookup testname1.example.com.` ?

Comment: If the server has no internet, the DNSSEC configuration won't work.

Comment: The zone files should have an entry for ns1.example.com, both forward and reverse `ns      IN      A       10.0.0.100` and `100              IN      PTR     ns.example.org.`

Comment: In file `dhcp.conf` the `host testname1` is missing `  option domain-name-servers 10.0.0.100; option domain-name "example.com"; option routers 10.0.0.1;` as it is outside of the serviced range `110-125`.

Comment: 1) wait, *both* forward and reverse zone files should have A and PTR records for NS servers? Not just PTR record in reverse zone and A record in forward zone? I have to check, but missing A record in forward zone and PTR record in reverse zone is probably just mistake when I was selecting what parts of zone files to copy, they are a lot longer then the coppied parts.

Comment: No, each file should have one of the values. Sorry for the confusion. Please use this: the forward file should have the `ns1 IN A 10.0.0.100`, the reverse file the `100 IN PTR ns1.example.org.`

Comment: 2) You are right that the hosts are not in subnet range, it's strange, but they are getting correct router - 10.0.0.1, I should probably create a group for them.
3) I don't get why DNSSEC won't work if there is no internet connection, as far as I know it's not needed, it just specifies if DNS should use keys when talking to others (be it another DNS or in this case DDNS). Sorry, I may be missing something, this is completely new field for me.

Comment: 3) I can test and post results of the dig tomorrow, package is already installed from previous tests I made. Do you want results when used directly on server, or on some client PC?

Comment: DNSSEC keys have absolutely nothing in common with HMAC-MD5 based keys {[read this link](http://romana.now.ie/james/tsig.html)} for interprocess exchange.

Comment: About 3), it doesn't matter from where, the answer from the server should be the same.

Comment: @sorontar
1) I have checked that ns1 has PTR record in reverse and A record in forward zone file.
2) I have moved broadcast-address and routers options to global parameters in dhcpd.conf and domain-name-servers option changed from ns1.example.com to 10.0.0.100.
3a) nslookup testname1.example.com returns: server can't find testname1.example.com: NXDOMAIN
3b) I will add results of dig test to the end of the question, as there is not enough space in comments, will be done in a minute.

Comment: 1) fine 2) missing `option domain-name-servers 10.0.0.100` for fixed address? 3a) as you reported that the issue with that resolution is REFUSED, it seems that the ip from where the resolution is being done is not accepted as able to resolve (does `nslookup testname2.example.com` resolve correctly?.

Comment: Please. Move everything to a backup directory. Start from zero [following this page](https://wiki.debian.org/DDNS). After it works exactly as is in that page, adapt the configuration "one step at a time" to your needs, if it breaks, you will know immediately where. I believe that there may be a problem in asking the dhcdp server for an address not inside the dhcp served range 10.0.0.110-10.0.0.120 but I do not have the time to build a whole new configuration to test.

Comment: Asking for testname2 or testname2.example.com is working, when I allow recursion in named.conf, asking for testname1: refused changes into SERVFAIL for nslookup and dig. It can't connect to internet after all.
I plan to start from scratch if everything else fails, but that's not so easy in my working environment when lots of people depend on at least basic functionality - I need to keep dhcp working as long as there are people connected. I will be able to do that in a week or two on weekend :)

Comment: You can setup DNS servers on port 5353 and DHCP server on 10.56.78.100 to 200 range in some alternative box (or even set a full network with virtual computers on a virtual network if you know how to) to make your tests without stoping the running one(s). Good Luck :-)